# Sequelize how to properly create a User Data with constraints?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

This question does not seek answer as "best practice", but rather the more appropriate way compared to what I have below.

Basically I have a `User` model/table that has this associate with `UserScore` model/table.

```
User.belongsTo(models.UserScore, { 
  foreignKey: {
    name: "userScoreId",
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 1
  },
  as: "score",
  targetKey: "id"
})
```

---

And then the `UserScore` model is defined as:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserScore = sequelize.define('UserScore', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, unique: true, primaryKey: true },
    score: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    coins: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  UserScore.associate = function (models) {
    UserScore.hasMany(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userScoreId",
      sourceKey: "id"
    })
  };
  return UserScore;
};
```

The **PROBLEM** that I have is that I feel like I'm doing my Sequelize queries below incorrectly.

First I create `UserScore` assuming that I know the `userId`, using Facebook works because I can get `id` from Facebook. BUT NOT with **signup with email and password**! This is the **first problem**.

And after creating the `UserScore`, I then create a `User` data. This just feels so wrong. Although it works well with login with Facebook because like I said, I have the `userId` for creating `UserScore`, but what if I don't have it (e.g. using sign up with email and password)?

EDIT: The question is related to the error about constraints, because I tried making a `User` data without making a `UserScore` first. I can't it reproduce now because I've fixed it using UUId (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-int).

---

**AuthController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    // SIGN UP WITH EMAIL AND PASSWORD
    signup: async (req, res, next) => {
      const email = req.body.email
      const password = req.body.password

      if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(403).send({
          message: "Error! Required parameters are: {email} and {password}."
        })
      }

      // Check if there is a user with the same email
      db.User.findOne({
        where: { email: email }
      })
        .then(data => {
          if (data) {
            return res.status(409).send({
              message: "Email is already in use."
            })
          }

          // Create a new user...
          const newUser = {
            fbId: null,
            email: email,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            photoUrl: null
          }

          const newUserScore = {
            score: 0,
            userId: id, //// <---------- NO IDEA!!!
            coins: 0
          }

          db.UserScore.create(newUserScore)
            .then(userScoreData => {

              db.User.create(newUser)
                .then(data => {
                  console.log("Created new user! ✅")
                  // Generate the token
                  const token = signToken(newUser)
                  // Respond with token
                  res.status(200).json({ token })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log("Error creating a new user!!!." + err)
                  return res.status(409).send({
                    message: "An error has occured while creating a new user"
                  })
                })

            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log("Error creating user score.")
              done(err, null, err.message)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "An error has occured while retrieving data."
          })
        })
    }
}
```

**User Relations**:

[image]

Comment: The question title is about constraints. What constraints are you trying to create? This isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried making a `User` data without making a `UserScore` first.

The foreign key constraint you have defined between `User` and `UserScore` 
will never allow you to add a `UserScoreId` in the table `User` that does not exist in the `UserScore` table, as this will violate 
the SQL foreign key constraint. This is indeed a constraint !

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), 
you are modeling the fact that a user may have one or more score(s), 
if so, it's the `userId` that should be in the `UserScore` table.

This way, if the user with the same email does not exist you can add the user first then add the user score.

So you have to change how you defined your `sequelize` associations 
and set `userId` as a foreign key on the `UserScore` table.

Here's how you could define the associations

```
//will add userId to UserScore table 
User.hasMany(UserScore, {
    foreignKey: { name: "userId", allowNull: false, defaultValue: 1 },
    as: "score",
    targetKey: "id"
})

//same here, will add userId to UserScore table 
UserScore.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    sourceKey: "id"
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I'd like to make the `UserScore` table to be much like a reference table, I don't know if there's such a thing, you know to separate the scores and other stuff of the users. Nevertheless, I actually thought about this approach. The problem was about the constraint and you corrected it. Meanwhile, I retained my seemingly wrong approach and solved the same problem by using uuid-int to generate id uniquely.

Comment: This allows you to separate scores to any  other stuff of the users, as the table`UserScore` holds only user id. Or what do you mean by "reference table" ?

Comment: Don't mind that `reference table` thing. I'm a newbie in both SQL and Server side stuff. I guess what I was just trying to say is that I separated score, coins, and other user account stuff from the `User` table, which I should've not (I believe) if I am not to follow your answer above :D But it's there already, maybe in my next project, I'll do better. Thanks again!